IS IT OK TO STORE WATER OF HOLY RIVERS MIXED WITH EACH OTHER?
When we say the mantra Gange cha Yamune chaiva Godavari Swaraswati Narmada Sindhu Kaveri...
Kalas, Kushi etc....
My cousin just mixed disproportionate amounts (Unkown) of waters into one bottle.
Thankfully it is Kaveri, Saraswati, Yamuna, I do not have specific uses in Abhisheka. On Sree Yantra I will be using these together?
Or is it better to re-buy these?
Storing these at home, not sore if accidentally am creating some unknown energy hull by remixing these rivers once seperated without invoking mantras/ Puja.

There is nothing to panic. This is good. Just as you mentioned earlier, when we invoke in kalasham, we invoke all 7 rivers, 7 seas, etc, so nothing to worry about.
